# Should I be using KVO or NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a CoreLocation singleton that has a `location` property. When I have retrieved the location I need to notify other controllers that the location has been received. However, I'm torn between using Key Value Observing and NSNotificationCenter. I currently have it set up as using KVO, but it seems to crash when the KVO property is nil. Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KVO is extremely tricky and hacky (and, as you've discovered, easy to crash). Where possible, and especially where (as here) your goal is to broadcast anonymously, use a notification.

Comment: I'm also wondering whether you've set this up correctly. For example, if your property is not `dynamic` it can't be observed in Swift. I probably shouldn't tell you that, because KVO is evil, but you might want to use KVO anyway in spite of my warnings... :)

Comment: Thanks for this. Actually I hadn't set it as dynamic... It had been working apart from the odd crash though. I used `willChangeValueForKey("location")` and `didChangeValueForKey("location")` around the location variable. What does adding this keyword do?

Comment: How does KVO work? It effectively method-swizzles the setter for your property. (The truth is more complicated, but in any case, this is why I regard KVO as the work of the devil.) It can't do that unless the property is `dynamic`. Your `will` and `did` obviated the necessity, however.